# Modifying web.config while the site is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

Whenever I need to make any changes in development I used to modify the web.config file and restart the app in IIS/Visual studio. This method used to work in production too. Today when I changed the web config file I got the error message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a 
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The configuration file has been changed by another program.

I think that this caused because the application was still running. I know the purpose of an `app_offline.htm` file and that it can be placed in the root of the application to stop serving out new request. The reason why I cannot do that is because even if I put an app_offline.htm file it does not reflect the changes instantly and this creates chaos.Sometimes when I try from a different network the changes reflects instantly. Could be a cache problem ?

It usually takes take .5 to 1.5 hours for the changes to reflected back for the clients. Sometimes the changes are applied instantly as well. My hosting provider is not that great and I am on shared hosting. So they said that they have 11 load balancing servers and the changes need to get updated on all the servers and could take some time.

To fix the above mentioned error ,I had to personally call the hosting providers and ask them to restart the application pool.

**1) Does anyone know what can be done so that I don't have to call up the hosting provider every time?**

**2) Is the load balancer problem true? I am not sure if it is or they are making it up**

**PS I do not have Remote IIS access.**

Cheers,
Varun

Comment: I was under the impression that IIS was designed to detect changes in web.config; reload it and restart the app without the user having to say recycle the apppool let alone restart IIS. However your question is interesting

Comment: Wow your hosting provider isn't good. I'd recommend moving. Changes shouldn't take hours and the fools should have created a private apppool just for you and allowed you to recyle it when you want

Comment: They are not good and we are evaluating our options to move to azure

Comment: Does anyone have any info on this ?